# Texlive 2018 install kills tex

Tags: kile, texlive-2017, texlive-2018

I recently upgraded from Texlive 2017 to Texlive 2018 by default through dnf on a fedora 28 system, using Kile as the front end. My tex installation now fails to produce anything. I have removed texlive 2016 and uninstalled and reinstalled the 2018 version with no joy. On using Kile, my output gives me

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/<username>/work/science/chemistry/mod_io_mat"
*****     pdflatex -shell-escape
*****
```

---

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
```

I'm at a loss and under some time pressure....

Comment: I should say that Kile is the Latex front end, using pdfLaTex as the compiler

Comment: What happens when you run pdfLaTeX from the terminal?

Comment: I haven't tried that Joseph - will give it a go now....

Comment: pdflatex mim_ps_1718_q.tex does compile. This is strange as I used the system check in Kile first... Looks like a Kile problem. Thank you Joseph, I should have checked this first.

Comment: You're not the first Kile user to ask. I'm not a Kile user, but, chekc if the Kile configuration it self has a setting about where LaTeX is (instead of getting it from the path).

Comment: Thanks dalief - I've checked kile and I can't see anything that will give me this information. Looking at the texlive 2018, it seems that there is a glitch with texlive-pdftex-7, which obsoletes the current install apparently...

Comment: you said you have installed texlive 2018 but the log you show is texlive 2017.

Comment: Hi David - true. I can't seem to work this out - I removed the older versions but still end up with this version, even though I have removed and reinstalled the 'latest' version via dnf several times. I've gone in and manually removed texmf directories from the system and this still bubbles up. This has also been started by a default upgrade via dnf, which is beyond annoying.

Comment: Hi all, I've just installed texmaker and all seems to be well and will compile everything to .pdf. Seems that it's a kile problem, which I don't have time to diagnose/fix. V. frustrating but sorted...

Comment: check in Kile where `Settings->ConfigureKile->Tools->Build->LaTeX` is pointing to, as soon as you have the time.

Comment: I've returned to this problem as TexWorks was buggy and slow and TexMaker was also slow and would hang. The fix I used was to remove texlive via `dnf remove texlive texlive-scheme-full texlive-collection-science texlive* kile` and then `locate texmf` which allowed me to remove everything with `rm -rf `, especially the \home\<suername>\.texlive2017 hidden file. Reboot and then reinstall everything in a one-er incl. kile and now I'm in typeset heaven.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by the OP

Comment: I think that's fair @samcarter. It works fine now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just to add to the soup of comments: This is a bug in Kile. It _should_ fetch the paths to the executables from the current `$PATH`, but it doesn't. A few days ago I was doing the same and found the bug report somewhere. I worked around the issue by hardcoding the path of the TL2018 executables in `Settings->Configure Kile->Tools->Build`. Definitely not pretty, but it will work until 2019.